# pandas how to have different color line graph

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, plot

I have a dataframe,

```
index block array_size  time
0   2   100 0.102710
1   2   1000    0.356194
2   2   10000   2.884903
3   2   100000  28.484935
4   2   1000000 293.656645
5   2   8000000 91286.889516
6   4   100 0.103323
7   4   1000    0.347484
8   4   10000   2.799290
9   4   100000  27.3598
```

[image]

I want to have different color for different value of block (2 and 4. second column)

My code for this plot is `df.plot(x='array_size', y='time')`
How can I have different color for each variables ?

Comment: You plot only one variable (time). What do you mean by 'each variable'?

Comment: @DYZ each block. my bad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either just plot them each separately with a simple `groupby`, or if you are willing to use `seaborn` that will allow you to specify a column for `hue`

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,4))

for idx, gp in df.groupby('block'):
    gp.plot(x='array_size', y='time', ax=ax, label=idx)
plt.show()
```

[image]

With `seaborn` (at least 0.9) you can just do:

```
sns.lineplot(data=df, x='array_size', y='time', hue='block')
```

---

Since you have many `'blocks'` the standard color cycler isn't going to cut it. You can adjust that easily with `ax.set_prop_cycle`

#### Sample Data

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': np.tile(np.arange(1,11,1),20),
                   'y': np.random.randint(1,25,200),
                   'block': np.repeat(np.arange(1,21,1),10)})
```

#### Code:

```
fig, ax= plt.subplots(figsize=(8,4))

colors = sns.color_palette("coolwarm", df.block.nunique())
ax.set_prop_cycle('color', colors)

for idx, gp in df.groupby('block'):
    gp.plot(x='x', y='y', ax=ax, legend=False)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This should do it.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

for unq_value in df['block'].unique():
    mask = df['block'] == unq_value
    df_subset = df[mask]
    plt.plot(df_subset['array_size'], df_subset['time'])
plt.show()
```

Here, we are finding the unique values in block column. Then subset the dataframe for each of the unique value, and then plotting separately for each subset of dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `color` parameter to the `.plot` method to pass in a list of colors, one for each column.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.line.html

[image]